# Read PostgreSQL tables with asyncpg and convert to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, asyncpg

I am trying to read a postgresql table using asyncpg.

```
conn = await asyncpg.connect(user='user', password='pass',
                                 database='dba', host='host', port='5432')


values = await conn.fetch('''SELECT * FROM my_table''')

values=pd.DataFrame(values)
values
```

With above code I get the table all rows values for every columns but doesn't show column names and it shows columns numbering instead of their proper names. How to correct this?

I've also tried this:

```
columns = [c.name for c in values.get_attributes()]
```

```
values = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_attributes'
```

Comment: did you try pd.read_sql ?

Comment: @Clegane I've tried: `dataframe=pd.read_sql(sql=values, con = conn)` and have this error: `TypeError: cursor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'`. @Clegane